# Java properties: .properties files vs xml?

Tags: java, xml, properties

I'm a newbie when it comes to properties, and I read that XML is the preferred way to store these. I noticed however, that writing a regular .properties file in the style of

```
foo=bar
fu=baz
```

also works. This would mean a lot less typing (and maybe easier to read and more efficient as well). So what are the benefits of using an XML file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In XML you can store more complex (e.g. hierarchical) data than in a properties file. So it depends on your usecase. If you just want to store a small number of direct properties a properties file is easier to handle (though the Java properties class can read XML based properties, too).

It would make sense to keep your configuration interface as generic as possible anyway, so you have no problem to switch to another representation ( e.g. by using [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) ) if you need to.

Comment: FYI: The java.util.Properties class does support XML:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Edit: the urls above are mangled the closing paren should be part of the links.

Comment: please check/add Mike Sickler's answer before coming to a conclusion. You certainly don't want to miss his point.

Answer (score 16):

The biggest benefit to using an XML file is that XML declares its encoding, while .properties does not.

If you are translating these properties files to N languages, it is possible that these files could come back in N different encodings. And if you're not careful, you or someone else could irreversibly corrupt the character encodings.

Comment: That's simply wrong. Java property-files are defined to have ISO8859_1 as encoding, every other encoding is against specification. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html for more information.

Comment: Dude- it doesn't 'declare' its encoding in the file.

Comment: You're missing my point. A text editor or other tool will obey an XML file's declared encoding, but since a properties file has no such declaration, it's up to the user to decide what encoding to save it in. That is a recipe for trouble if you're doing translation.

Comment: "Java property-files are defined to have ISO-8859-1 as encoding". False.  That's only required/assumed if using the old methods "load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) " By simply using "load(Reader) / store(Writer, String)" (and opening the file in the proper encoding) you can use UTF-8 or whatever.

Comment: Agree with it, It corrupts the file ... u can take a property file in french language, open it on windows IntellijIdea, and same file open in IntellijIdea on linux. u'll get the corruption

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answered the question posed! Why was it not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 9):

If you have a lot of repeating data, it can be simpler to process

```
<connections>
  <connection>this</connection>
  <connection>that</connection>
  <connection>the other</connection>
</connections>
```

than it is to process

```
connection1=this
connection2=that
connection3=the other
```

especially if you are expecting to have to store a *lot* of data, or it must be stored in a definite hierarchy

If you are just storing a few scalar values though, I'd go for the simple Properties approach every time

Comment: Yeah, I was planning to use it for different values. None of the data is shared with the other files.

Answer (score 5):

If you have both hierarchical data & duplicate namespaces, then use XML.

1) To emulate just a hierarchical structure in a properties file, simply use dot notation:

```
a.b=The Joker
a.b.c=Batgirl
a.b=Batman
a.b=Superman
a.b.c=Supergirl
```

So, complex (hierarchical) data representation is *not a reason to use xml.

2) For just repeating data, we can use a 3rd party library like ini4j to peg explicitly in java a count identifier on an implicit quantifier in the properties file itself.

```
a.b=The Joker
a.b=Batgirl
a.b=Batman
```

is translated to (in the background)

```
a.b1=The Joker
a.b2=Batgirl
a.b3=Batman
```

However, numerating same name properties still doesn't maintain the specific parent-child relationships. ie. how do we represent whether Batgirl is with The Joker or Batman?

So, xml is required when both features are needed. We can now decide if the 1st xml entry is what we want or the 2nd.

```
[a]
   [b]Joker[/b]
   [b]
       [c]Batgirl[/c]
   [/b]
[a]
```

--or--

```
[a]
   [b]Batman[/b]
   [b]
       [c]Batgirl[/c]
   [/b]
[/a]
```

Further detail in ....
          http://ilupper.blogspot.com/2010/05/xml-vs-properties.html

Comment: Hi Kjetil, the point here is what a properties entry can represent and what an xml entry can represent. Fundamentally, because the property entry lacks a close semantic, it's structure is less "3D" as most of my colleagues put it. Therefore, if one attempts to emulate a hierachical structure with properties over xml, they would require a control bit. Otherwise, ambiguity arises.

Answer (score 1):

XML is handy for complex data structures and or relationships. It does a decent job for having a "common language" between systems.

However, xml comes at a cost.  Its is heavy to consume. You've got to load a parser, ensure the file is in the correct format, find the information etc...

Whereas properties files is pretty light weight and easy to read.  Works for simple key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data you're encoding. With XML, you can define a more complex representation of the configuration data in your application. Take something like the struts framework as an example. Within the framework you have a number of Action classes that can contain 1...n number of forward branches. With an XML configuration file, you can define it like:

```
<action class="MyActionClass">
  <forward name="prev" targetAction="..."/>
  <forward name="next" targetAction="..."/>
  <forward name="help" targetAction="..."/>
</action>
```

This kind of association is difficult to accomplish using just the key-value pair representation of the properties file. Most likely, you would need to come up with a delimiting character and then include all of the forward actions on a single property separated by this delimiting character. It's quite a bit of work for a hackish solution.

Yet, as you pointed out, the XML syntax can become a burden if you just want to state something very simple, like set feature blah to true.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantages of XML:

1. It is hard to read - the tags make it look busier than it really is
2. The hierarchies and tags make it hard to edit and more prone to human errors
3. It is not possible to "append" to an XML property file to introduce a new property or provide an overriding value for an existing property so that the last one wins.  The ability to append a property can be very powerful - we can implement a property management logic around this so that certain properties are "hot" and we don't need to restart the instance when these change

The Java property file solves the above problems.  Consistent naming conventions and dot notation can help in solving the issue of hierarchy.