# Spring @Value from .properties file null in debug eclipse

Tags: java, spring, debugging

The purpose of my code is to load some settings value from a *.properties file so that I later can use these values in some if-statements in my code. I want to load in some list-structure, but since that seems hard, an array will do. I have not really gotten that far, since I am stuck at the trivial matter of loading just a String from the properties file.

When I try to debug my code that is using some spring specific data. I get some interesting behaviour, pointing on the definition in the code right above the breakpoint gives me that the variable value is null.

```
@Value(value = "${ViewableReportFilter.allStates.verify}")
String verifyStringStates;

public ViewableReportFilter() {
    viewStates = null;
    log.debug("Read in properties for states: verify:" + verifyStringStates);

     /*BREAKPOINT HERE*/
```

in my my.properties file:

```
ViewableReportFilter.allStates.verify=ONHOLD
```

And my config to use the properties-file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/my.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Comment: do other properties from that file work? maybe the file is not loaded

Comment: Other properties get loaded.

Comment: I want to see your declaration for the `ViewableReportFilter` bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the constructor, and added Autowire annotation. No changes in the properties file, no XML.

```
String arrayOfStrings;

@Autowired
public ViewableReportFilter(
        @Value("${TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.verify}") String[] verifyStringStates) {
        arrayOfStrings = verifyStringStates;


public logViewableReportFilter() {
    log.debug("Read in properties for states: verify:" + arrayOfString);
}
```

Comment: I still don't think this is doing what you think it's doing. You really haven't provided the details we need in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't set the fields of an object before that object is created. The first thing Spring does is use reflection to instantiate your class. It'll use either `Class#newInstance()` or use `Constructor#newInstance()` depending on the context. Only when the constructor has finished its work and returned can Spring, again using reflection, set the value of fields.

An alternative is to put a `@Value` annotated parameter in the constructor parameter list and set your field inside your constructor from the argument that's given to it by Spring.

```
public ViewableReportFilter(@Value String verify) {
    this.verifyStringStates = verify;
    ...
```

Go through the [Spring documentation for its IoC container.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) It explains all of this in much detail.

Comment: Doing this makes Spring throw me another error. No default constructor!, adding an empty constructor makes the one with parameters being skipped

Comment: @DavidKarlsson Again it depends on how you are expecting your bean to be created. Sorry, I was assuming with `@Component`. If you are using `<bean>` declarations, you need to specify a `constructor-arg`.

Comment: @DavidKarlsson If there is something you need to do with the `verifyStringStates` during initialization, use a `@PostConstruct` annotated method instead so that Spring has time to set the value of your field, then call it.

Comment: I havent specified any new <bean> in the xml, is this necessary to use values from my properties file (the properties file is used by other classes already)

Comment: @DavidKarlsson Do you have a `<bean>` for `ViewableReportFilter`? You cannot use it as is if you expect to use a constructor that accepts a parameter.

Comment: I dont use the XML approach, hence my bean is only declared in the properties file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380156/java-properties-properties-files-vs-xml

Comment: @david Please edit your question with your configuration for this bean. Or use the `@PostConstruct` solution.

Comment: I use automatic bean registration, as I said no bean in the xml!

Comment: @David What do you mean by automatic bean registration? Be more specific. Do you mean with `component-scan`? Is your class annotated with `@Component`?

Comment: http://sethuramanmurali.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/load-properties-file-using-spring-context/

Comment: @David You're completely misunderstanding what that is doing. The property you declare in the file is just a property, it's not a bean declaration. Is there anywhere in your code where you are doing `new ViewableReportFilter()`? If yes, then you are expecting Spring to set values in an object it isn't managing. This is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

`@Value(value = "${allStates.verify}")`

And in your property my.properties:

`allStates.verify=ONHOLD`