# Integration test to verify values in spring properties file

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing

In my project based on a Java+Spring backend i have extracted a list of authority properties to a [.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380156/java-properties-properties-files-vs-xml). How do i verify that the requested parameters exist in the properties file in testing?

Is there a way to integrate this properties file in my integration testing?

Properties file:

```
#Viewable Report Filter, Ordered list of states to be viewed in each step of the web-gui
TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.verify=ONHOLD_HR,VERIFY,PREPARE,CONFIRM,CONFIRM_HR,CONFIRM_MGR,CONFIRM_RM,AGRESSO_IN_PROGRESS,CLOSED
TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.manager=PREPARE,ONHOLD_FINANCE,ONHOLD_HR,AGRESSO_ERROR,CONFIRM,CONFIRM_HR,CONFIRM_MGR,CONFIRM_RM,AGRESSO_IN_PROGRESS,CLOSED
TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.prepare=CONFIRM,CONFIRM_HR,CONFIRM_MGR,CONFIRM_RM,ONHOLD_FINANCE,CLOSED
TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.confirm=CONFIRM_MGR,CONFIRM_HR,CONFIRM_RM,ONHOLD_HR,CLOSED


#Handleable Report Filter, Ordered list of states to be viewed in each step of the web-gui
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.verify=APPROVE,ONHOLD_EMPLOYEE,ONHOLD_FINANCE,AGRESSO_ERROR
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.manager=VERIFY
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.prepare=PREPARE,ONHOLD_HR
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.hr=CONFIRM_HR
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.mgr=CONFIRM_MGR,CONFIRM_HR
TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.rm=CONFIRM_RM
```

Here's how i access the values:

```
@Autowired
    public TMSHandleableReportService(
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.verify}") String[] verifyStringStates,
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.manager}") String[] managerStringStates,
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.prepare}") String[] prepareStringStates,
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.hr}") String[] confirmHRStringStates,
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.mgr}") String[] confirmMGRStringStates,
            @Value("${TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.rm}") String[] confirmRMStringStates) {

        handleStates = new HashMap<String, List<TMSState>>();


        handleStates.put(
                "verify",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(verifyStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.verify"));

        handleStates.put(
                "manager",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(managerStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.manager"));

        handleStates.put(
                "prepare",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(prepareStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.prepare"));
        handleStates.put(
                "confirm.hr",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(confirmHRStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.hr"));
        handleStates.put(
                "confirm.mgr",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(confirmMGRStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.mgr"));
        handleStates.put(
                "confirm.rm",
                loadTMSStateFromStringArray(confirmRMStringStates,
                        "TMSViewableReportFilter.allStates.confirm.rm"));
```

Verifying that the keys exist in the properties file is enough. I.e. verifying the occurrence of TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.verify, TMSHandleableReportFilter.allStates.prepare... etc.

Comment: Inject the property values into a unit test and write test methods to confirm they're valid?

Comment: i want to verify that the values are in the properties file, i e. i want to verify the existance of the data in an integration test, i dont want to unit test my class using the data. This is already done

Comment: All you need to do is using an application context for your test that includes your property file. After that you can autowire properties through the @Value like you did your Service and check them.

Comment: I meant *specifically* what I said--inject the actual properties into the unit test. Treat the unit test itself as a bean, and as @mvb13 explained, autowire the values onto fields in the unit test. Then just write methods to check that the values themselves are "valid", whatever that means in your context. This is distinct from writing a test that calls your service layer, which relies on the values.

Answer (score 0):

"In my project based on a Java+Spring backend i have extracted a list of authority properties to a .properties file. How do i verify that the requested parameters exist in the properties file in testing?"
My answer is - you don't need to do that, once Spring cannot autowire value from property file, server won't start (or any other integration te. There is no need to verify that.